# Why is an airfoil shaped like a teardrop?

Tags: flow, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence, aircraft

I understand the reason airfoils are cambered on the top: to create lift. But one would assume this would result in aircraft wings having a semicircle-shaped design. Why is the cross-section of an airfoil instead more reminiscent of a teardrop on its side and cut horizontally? Why is the front thicker than the back?

Comment: Having a longer path for the air over the top of the wing isn't actually all that important. The important part is having the wing at an angle to the airflow. The teardrop is to make it easy for the air to turn the corner around the leading edge of the wing, but difficult to turn the corner at the trailing edge. This page has a good explanation: http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/airfoils.html#sec-airfoils

Comment: @RickyTensor, I think there's one more detail: A razor-thin leading edge would be better than a rounded leading edge if the air always hit the wing at just the perfect angle of attack, but it would stall at pretty much any other angle. The rounded leading edge offers more drag, but it performs without any abrupt changes over a significant range of angles of attack.

Comment: ObXKCD: [Airfoil](http://xkcd.com/803/).

Comment: @SteveSummit Oh I completely understand that the equal time arguement is wrong

Comment: Worth considering that a teardrop (or better, a raindrop) is defined as what happens to water when you put it in a stream of flowing air

Comment: @foobarbecue I actually did think about that but I dont quite see how it could be used in this scenario Edit: Actually well I suppose the drag forces applied to a drop of liquid turn it into a teardrop, So I suppose once a wing is already teardrop shaped then the drag forces would be streamlined?

Comment: Actually, the shape of a raindrop is Not what most people think it is. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/231756/313822

Comment: @RickyTensor The angle of attack is also the wrong variable. The key question is, how much air is moving downward at which speed after the air foil has passed through. That means, that the angles of the rear edge determine the amount of lift much more because they dictate the angle at which the air leaves the airfoil. The amount of air that is moved downwards is mostly controlled by the length of the wing's cross section. The angle of attack is only useful *after* you have settled on a fixed wing shape, precisely because it adds to the trailing edge angles.

Answer (score 34):

The airfoil shape is optimized for two features

- a maximal [lift coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_coefficient) $c_L$, to get a big lift force
- a minimal [drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient) $c_D$, to get a small drag force

Maximizing the lift coefficient $c_L$ alone would, as you said,
demand for a semi-circle-like shape, like this:
[image]

Minimizing the drag coefficient $c_D$ alone would
demand for a tear-drop-like shape (with a round front end
and a thin back end. See the *streamlined body*
in the image below.

[image]
<sub>(image from [Wikipedia - Drag coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient))</sub>

Putting these two requirements together you arrive
at the typical airfoil shape which is kind of a compromise between
the semi-circle and the tear-drop shapes from above.
[image]
<sub>(image from [Wikipedia - Airfoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airfoil))</sub>

Comment: There was also a lot of practical research (e.g. measuring things in wind tunnels) that went in to determining optimal airfoil shapes for particular conditions.  See for instance NACA (the predecessor to NASA) airfoils: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil

Comment: Why is a teardrop shape so streamline?

Comment: @JamesDavis I think it is because the thin tail prevents turbulence. See
[here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Pressure-drag-behind-a-sphere-and-comparison-with-a-streamlined-shape-For-a-streamlined_fig1_333103343).

Comment: I'm curious: is there a more explicit mathematical expression for the idealized airfoil shape as you describe - even if not a "closed form" in terms of some more general functions, then at least like an infinite sum?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer: If you're willing to assume "no turbulence," I imagine there's some ungodly differential equation you can try to solve, at which point you'll have a spherical-cow airfoil that doesn't actually work. If you admit that turbulence is a thing, then it's a really hard problem.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer There is no "ideal" airfoil shape since every airfoil is a tradeoff. A glider has a different preferred airfoil family compared to an airliner which again has a different preferred airfoil family compared to a slow light aircraft. You choose airfoils based on what mission it needs to do. There is a an equation that can be applied as a field to figure out the behavior of any object in a fluid: the Navier-Stokes equation.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer ... modern airfoil designers use tools like XFLR5 to apply the Navier-Stokes equation to 3D objects (computational fluid dynamics) to characterize the behavior of airfoils then feed the result into another program that modifies the airfoil a bit to feed it back into XLFR5. The airfoil will randomly mutate and evolve to meet certain design goals.

Comment: @slebetman : So then the two conditions given in the post do not uniquely define any particular shape, then? Yes, one may design for other parameters, but if we ask "is there a unique shape that, in two dimensions, optimizes both the drag and lift when subject to a uniform incoming flow?" is the answer "yes" or "no" and why? What other parameters must be fixed to uniquely specify the shape?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer You need to add additional data. You need to ask "for a wing with chord of 3m flying at 200km/h what shape would generate the best L/D ratio?" which will give you a different answer from "for a wing with chord of 5m flying at 900km/h what shape would generate the best L/D ratio?". The answer depends on the Reynolds number the wing operates in and Reynolds number changes depending on scale (wing chord), airspeed, air pressure etc.

Comment: .. Of course, no airplane (not even paper airplanes) operate at only one speed so you then have to compromise **again** to get a plane that performs OK at take-of/landing speeds and optimal at cruise. Just one example, the airfoil for a bungee-launched radio-controlled gilder would be different from the airfoil of a towed radio-controlled glider because the bungee-launched need to lower drag further to get a higher launch height but the towed glider can optimize for a higher lift airfoil because the towing aircraft can release it at any altitude

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Here are the 4 factors that affect Reynolds number: fluid (air) density, fluid (air) viscosity, (air) flow speed, size of object. Of the 4, 3 are variable and you can hardcode the viscosity of air unless you plan to also fly in things that are not air like pure hydrogen or water or oil. Of course, L/D ratio (optimizes both the lift and drag) is just one design criteria. Max L/D is almost never the same as Max lift (CL Max) so in some circumstances where you don't need to travel far but you need to lift a lot of weight you may choose CL Max instead of Max L/D

Comment: @The_Sympathizer There's a reason why aerodynamic design is still an art (or black magic) rather than a mechanical process. Our tools just give us the ability to test our designs (we can sort of cheat using evolutionary programming) instead of doing the design work for us. We depend on human intuition and rules-of-thumb to design an airfoil (or even an entire airplane), then we test to see if it is good.

Comment: In addition to the errors in the design optimization pointed out by @slebetman, the shape that's given as producing the maximum lift is also wrong - even assuming inviscid flow. A thin shape with semicircular upper and lower surfaces would have higher lift (as would many variations).

Comment: @slebetman : Thanks. Your first comment answers my question (in the negative). Likely the answer would benefit from including some of this info and that in subsequent comments.